# pivot table on big data (2.5m vs 2m)

Tags: python, mysql

i have a table with the following schema:
**userid | locationid | weight**

the basic problem is i need to create a **pivot table** such that i have **userid as rows** and **locationid as columns** and the weight in the matrix. This can be easily achieved in Excel and python but the main part of the problem that the size of my data is very large about **2.5million users and 2 million locations**. This is not possible in Excel and i do not have enough RAM to execute it through python.

Please tell me what is the best approach to go about it.

Possibly, there is one table(millions of rows) which looks like:

[image: Table1]

What he needs as output is: (millions of rows and columns)

[image: Table2]

Comment: what do you want to do with the pivot table? From what i get, you just want to use the user-id and location-id as keys to get an item out of the table?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the result? Are you aware that resulting pivot will require some terabites to store? I won't be easy manageable.

You can sort your data by userid and locationid and consider your data a sparse matrix.

Comment: I doubt you'll be writing your oun SVD :)
And almost all implementations are optimized for sparse matrices, that in your case there is no need to reconstruct full scale >4Tb martix. One such implementation is gensim package, http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/dist_lsi.html
For a overview of implementations I suggest looking here http://www.quora.com/What-s-the-best-parallelized-sparse-SVD-code-publicly-available